# Getting Error Accessing Twitter Data While Using LinqToTwitter

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I'm using this code to get name from screen name of twitter users:

```
    var users =
        (from user in twitterCtx.User
         where user.Type == UserType.Lookup &&
               user.ScreenName == "JoeMayo,LinqToTweeter"
         select user)
         .ToList();

    users.ForEach(user => Console.WriteLine("Name: " + user.Name));
```

but I received this error message:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. —-> System.ArgumentException: Query must contain one of either ScreenNameList or UserIdList parameters, but not both.

How can resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close - all you need to do is replace `user.ScreenName` with `user.ScreenNameList`, like this:

```
var users =
    (from user in twitterCtx.User
     where user.Type == UserType.Lookup &&
           user.ScreenNameList == "JoeMayo,LinqToTweeter"
     select user)
    .ToList();

users.ForEach(user => Console.WriteLine("Name: " + user.Name));
```

You can find a running [Demo in the source code](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/blob/master/Samples/net46/CSharp/ConsoleSamples/UserDemos.cs). There's [documentation available too](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/wiki/Querying-User-Details).